# ob_start including file echoing 1

Tags: php, html, css, ob-start

class function  (located php/php_includes/easyCMSv2.php)

```
    public function get_file($file){
     ob_start();
     include('php/'.$file);
     $file = ob_end_clean();
     return $file;
   }
```

stylesheet_config.php (located php/css)

```
<?php
  $blue = "#4C66A4";
  $red = "#A44C4C";
?>
```

stylesheet.php (located php/css)

```
<?php
  ob_start ("ob_gzhandler");
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])) {
     $if_modified_since = preg_replace('/;.*$/', '',   $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);
  } else {
     $if_modified_since = '';
  }
   $mtime = filemtime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
   $gmdate_mod = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $mtime) . ' GMT';

   if ($if_modified_since == $gmdate_mod) {
     header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
     exit;
   }
   header("Last-Modified: $gmdate_mod");
   header('Content-type: text/css');
   header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + (60*60*24*45)) . ' GMT');
   include_once('../php_includes/easyCMSv2.php');
   require('stylesheet_config.php');
   $cms = new Template($connect);
     if(isset($_GET['v'])){
       $cms->get_file('css/'.$_GET["v"].'.php');
     }
   ?>
```

`$_GET['v']` = 1-23-1

1-23-1.php (located php/css)

```
div{
  color:<?=$blue?>;
  background:<?=$red?>;
}
```

Though everytime I go to the url (either by a link tag or direct url) it returns `1` can anyone explain to me why it keeps returning 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ob_end_clean()` returns true or false (in your case, true, or 1). It does not return the actual buffer output.

You need to use another method to retrieve the buffer output: `ob_get_contents()`

```
public function get_file($file){
 ob_start();
 include('php/'.$file);
 $file = ob_get_contents(); /* *** */
 ob_end_clean();
 return $file;
```

}

Comment: WOW I over looked that way to much! I looked at it like 3,000 times now what an amateur mistake.

Comment: Sometimes just need another set of eyes on things, when you get too close ;)

Comment: Yes that is very very true. It sucks because I hate coming here asking some question because they end up being foolish and simple!